# Boys and Girls Probability

Tags: probability

From a class of 10 boys and 15 girls, prizes are randomly awarded to 3 children. Let N be the number of boys who win prizes. Construct the probability tables for the random variable N assuming that the sampling is done:

a. with replacement
$$P(N=j)=\binom{3}{j}(10/25)^j(15/25)^{3-j}$$
$$P(N=0)=\binom{3}{0}(10/25)^0(15/25)^{3}=27/125$$
$$P(N=1)=\binom{3}{1}(10/25)^1(15/25)^{2}=54/125$$
$$P(N=2)=\binom{3}{2}(10/25)^2(15/25)^{1}=36/125$$
$$P(N=3)=\binom{3}{3}(10/25)^3(15/25)^{0}=8/125$$5

b. without replacement

$$P(N=j)=\frac{\binom{10}{j}\binom{15}{3-j}}{\binom{25}{3}}$$
$$P(N=j)=\frac{\binom{10}{j}\binom{15}{3-j}}{2300}$$
$$P(N=0)=\frac{\binom{10}{0}\binom{15}{3}}{2300}=455/2300=91/460$$
$$P(N=1)=\frac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{15}{2}}{2300}=1050/2300=21/46$$
$$P(N=2)=\frac{\binom{10}{2}\binom{15}{1}}{2300}=675/2300=27/92$$
$$P(N=3)=\frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{15}{0}}{2300}=120/2300=6/115$$

Does my work look correct?

Comment: Yes. $\color{red}{\checkmark}$  The formula are appropriate and calculations seem correct.  (Note: a quick test you can apply yourself is to check the sum equals one.)

Comment: I have a suspicion that the first answer counts the probability that N prizes are given to boys. In other words, there is an invalid assumption that no boy receives more than one prize.

Comment: @user164587 it says the prizes are awarded to 3 children, so I think that makes it clear that each child can only receive one prize

Comment: The results for "without replacement" should be the same as "with replacement" then.